# Plotting multiple time series using VPlotContainers in Chaco. Limit to the number of VPlotContainer objects you can use

Tags: enthought, traitsui, chaco

I wish to plot multiple time series data stored in a `NumPy` array, in the same plot but with each time series offset, so effectively it has it's own Y axis.  I figured the best way to do this may be to put each series in a separate `VPlotContainer`, but when I call the `configure_traits()` call I am just getting a blank window.  Is the issue that I have too many time series for the machinery to handle?

```
class EEGPlot(HasTraits):
    plot = Instance(VPlotContainer)

    traits_view = View(
    Item('plot',editor=ComponentEditor(), show_label=False),
    width=1024, height=768, resizable=True, title="EEG Preview")

    def __init__(self, eegObject):
        super(EEGPlot, self).__init__()

        x = xrange(eegObject.windowStart, eegObject.windowEnd)

        plotNames = {}
        allPlots = []

        for idx, column in enumerate(eegObject.data[:,:].transpose()): # only included indexes to indicate array dimensions
            y = column
            plotdata = ArrayPlotData(x=x, y=y)
            myplot = Plot(plotdata)
            myplot.plot(("x", "y"), type="line", color="blue")
            plotNames["plot{0}".format(idx)] = myplot
            allPlots.append(plotNames["plot{0}".format(idx)])

        container = VPlotContainer(*allPlots)
        container.spacing = 0

        self.plot = container
```

So my EEGObject is a NumPy array with 2 dimensions.  Around 1500(row) by 65(col).  I am wondering if I getting the blank screen because I am doing something wrong or if I am just giving it too many containers?

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be that I was using the wrong tools to try and achieve what I needed.  VPlotContainers are for separating distinct plots (most likely from different data sources even) within a main display container.

When I fed a test array into the code in the original question that only had 5 columns, then each column plotted in a separate container, but when I increased the columns to above 6 then the UI window would appear blank.

So I guess the answer is that yes, there would appear to be a limit to the number of VPlotContainers you can use, but I don't know if this limit is absoloute or bound by the space dedicated to the main UI window or what.

Either way, using VPlotContainers is not an appropriate technique to display multiple time series data.  The correct object would be a MultiLinePlot if you wish the lines to be separated, or an OverlayPlotContainer.

http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/plot_types.html#multi-line-plot

I am also having issues using MultiLinePlot, but have moved this question to a separate thread here:

[Chaco MultiLinePlot - unable to get simple plot to display, wondering if package broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015052/chaco-multilineplot-unable-to-get-simple-plot-to-display-wondering-if-package)